# Would building just Lifesteal and attack speed be enough to carry a game as an AD carry?

Tags: league-of-legends

Like say if i build Wriggles, 2 Bloodthirsters, and 2 Phantom Dancers. would that be a viable build compared to the meta IE, PD, all of that nonsense? just curious as to how much of the game you can change without it affecting you at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Build wouldn't be viable in classic nor would any pure lifesteal build. Add an infinity edge, boots, atma's and get rid of a bloodthirter and a phantom dancer and you can be much more viable with that build. Final Build(Phantom, Infinity, Bloodthirster, Atma's, Boots,wriggles). This varies of course by character but adding armor/magic resist instead of one of those items can help too.

Comment: How does Atma's help when your average AD carry has less than 2k health and you have built no health items? Why not GA if you want some armor?

Answer (score 0):

Well...I believe because for example if they build armor, Last Whisperer will make you scary. Guardian Angel or Banshee's is your defensive item. Lifesteal will not save your from everything. The extra damage from I.E makes  you scary.

Not sure but yeah that's what I think.